# ggplot equivalent of gelman.plot MCMC diagnostic in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, bayesian, mcmc

I am creating a series of MCMC diagnostic plots in r using ggplot. I realize there is already a package available in gg for MCMC plotting, but much of this is for my own education as well as practical use. One thing I can't seem to figure out is how to generate the gelman.plot in a ggplot framework.

The gelman.diag function only returns a simple data point and I would like to recreate the complete running chart as shown in gelman.plot.

Is anyone familiar with the algorithmic structure of the gelman potential scale reduction factor and/or a means to port its output to ggplot?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't provided a reproducible example, so I've used the [example here](https://theoreticalecology.wordpress.com/2011/12/09/mcmc-chain-analysis-and-convergence-diagnostics-with-coda-in-r/). We need the object called `combinedchains` from that example. In order to avoid cluttering the answer, I've put the code for that at the end of this post.

Now we can run `gelman.plot` on `combined.chains`. This is the plot we want to duplicate:

```
library(coda)
gelman.plot(combined.chains)
```

[image]

To create a ggplot version, we need to get the data for the plot. I haven't done MCMC before, so I'm going to let `gelman.plot` generate the data for me. For your actual use case, you can probably just generate the appropriate data directly.

Let's look at what `gelman.plot` is doing: We can see the code for that function by typing the bare function name in the console. A portion of the function code is below. The `...` show where I've removed sections of the original code for brevity. Note the call to `gelman.preplot`, with the output of that function stored in `y`. Note also that `y` is returned invisibly at the end. `y` is a list containing the data we need to create a `gelman.plot` in ggplot.

```
gelman.plot = function (x, bin.width = 10, max.bins = 50, confidence = 0.95, 
          transform = FALSE, autoburnin = TRUE, auto.layout = TRUE, 
          ask, col = 1:2, lty = 1:2, xlab = "last iteration in chain", 
          ylab = "shrink factor", type = "l", ...) 
{ 
  ...
  y <- gelman.preplot(x, bin.width = bin.width, max.bins = max.bins, 
                      confidence = confidence, transform = transform, autoburnin = autoburnin)
...
  return(invisible(y))
}
```

So, let's get the data that `gelman.plot` returns invisibly and store it in an object:

```
gp.dat = gelman.plot(combinedchains)
```

Now for the ggplot version. First, `gp.dat` is a list and we need to convert the various parts of that list into a single data frame that ggplot can use.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)

df = data.frame(bind_rows(as.data.frame(gp.dat[["shrink"]][,,1]), 
                          as.data.frame(gp.dat[["shrink"]][,,2])), 
                q=rep(dimnames(gp.dat[["shrink"]])[[3]], each=nrow(gp.dat[["shrink"]][,,1])),
                last.iter=rep(gp.dat[["last.iter"]], length(gp.dat)))
```

For the plot, we'll melt `df` into long format, so that we can have each chain in a separate facet.

```
ggplot(melt(df, c("q","last.iter"), value.name="shrink_factor"), 
       aes(last.iter, shrink_factor, colour=q, linetype=q)) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=1, colour="grey30", lwd=0.2) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~variable, labeller= labeller(.cols=function(x) gsub("V", "Chain ", x))) +
  labs(x="Last Iteration in Chain", y="Shrink Factor",
       colour="Quantile", linetype="Quantile") +
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c(2,1))
```

[image]

---

**MCMC example code to create the `combinedchains` object (code copied from [here](https://theoreticalecology.wordpress.com/2011/12/09/mcmc-chain-analysis-and-convergence-diagnostics-with-coda-in-r/)):**

```
trueA = 5
trueB = 0
trueSd = 10
sampleSize = 31

x = (-(sampleSize-1)/2):((sampleSize-1)/2)
y =  trueA * x + trueB + rnorm(n=sampleSize,mean=0,sd=trueSd)

likelihood = function(param){
  a = param[1]
  b = param[2]
  sd = param[3]

  pred = a*x + b
  singlelikelihoods = dnorm(y, mean = pred, sd = sd, log = T)
  sumll = sum(singlelikelihoods)
  return(sumll)
}

prior = function(param){
  a = param[1]
  b = param[2]
  sd = param[3]
  aprior = dunif(a, min=0, max=10, log = T)
  bprior = dnorm(b, sd = 5, log = T)
  sdprior = dunif(sd, min=0, max=30, log = T)
  return(aprior+bprior+sdprior)
}

proposalfunction = function(param){
  return(rnorm(3,mean = param, sd= c(0.1,0.5,0.3)))
}

run_metropolis_MCMC = function(startvalue, iterations) {
  chain = array(dim = c(iterations+1,3))
  chain[1,] = startvalue
  for (i in 1:iterations) {
    proposal = proposalfunction(chain[i,])

    probab = exp(likelihood(proposal) + prior(proposal) - likelihood(chain[i,]) - prior(chain[i,]))

    if (runif(1)  <  probab){
      chain[i+1,] = proposal
    }else{
      chain[i+1,] = chain[i,]
    }
  }
  return(mcmc(chain))
}

startvalue = c(4,2,8)
chain = run_metropolis_MCMC(startvalue, 10000)

chain2 = run_metropolis_MCMC(startvalue, 10000)
combinedchains = mcmc.list(chain, chain2)
```

---

**UPDATE:** `gelman.preplot` is an internal `coda` function that's not directly visible to users. To get the function code, in the console type `getAnywhere(gelman.preplot)`. Then you can see what the function is doing and, if you wish, construct your own function to return the appropriate diagnostic data in a form more suitable for ggplot.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive and indeed impressive answer. I learned multiple things from your response beyond my original question. One additional question does arise though, which would be, is it possible to access the gelman.preplot routine directly? I attempted a search for accessing sub-functions and sub-routines within r packages and found nothing. Thank you again for your expertise.

Comment: I've added an update to my answer regarding `gelman.preplot`.